# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Tags: format, keystore

I have a JBoss 7.4.0 installation running in domain mode on a RHEL 7 platform. The JDK version is java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)

I am using the Jboss documentation How to Configure Server Security, specifically section 2.5: Configuring SSL/TLS for the legacy core management authentication mechanism. I am setting up Two-Way SSL/TLS.

I create a keystore, generate key pairs, export and import certificates. The storetype is JCEKS. (I have also tried using PCKS12 and JKS, same issue)

When I try to start the JBoss server I see the following error:
06:47:41,216 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final-redhat-00001
06:47:41,498 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001
06:47:41,514 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[Host Controller] 06:47:41,982 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final-redhat-00001
...
[Host Controller] 06:47:43,848 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /u01/redhat/jboss/domain_74/domain/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
[Host Controller] 06:47:43,851 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.SP1-redhat-00001
[Host Controller] 06:47:43,852 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.CertificateRealm.key-manager: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.core.management.security.realm.CertificateRealm.key-manager: Failed to start service
[Host Controller]       at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
...
[Host Controller] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in anonymous service: WFLYDM0018: Unable to start service
...
[Host Controller] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

So my understanding is the issue is with the keystore format, yet if I use another keystore format I get the same issue.

And, when I run the following command I get success:
./keytool -list -keystore $EAP_HOME/vault/h1vault.jceks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: JCEKS
Keystore provider: SunJCE

Your keystore contains 3 entries

h1server_alias, Sep 20, 2022, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 58:58:36:82:EE:B5:88:BB:AF:59:F6:17:F2:9B:D3:29:D6:CC:DD:02:04:E5:3B:50:8A:70:AB:5C:85:59:DD:25
h1vault, Sep 20, 2022, SecretKeyEntry,
host2_alias, Sep 20, 2022, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 62:07:76:CB:B7:B8:9C:89:6D:36:82:8B:5B:8A:E9:7E:8E:6A:23:8E:51:56:03:B9:F9:98:D3:DA:D4:53:B5:57

I would expect this command to fail if the keystore format was incorrect.

I have read all sorts of threads and so on about this but cannot find an answer.

Appreciate if anyone can suggest possible solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HiOK, well, I am trying to start an application server (JBoss) and when I do it tells me "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format", however, when I run the command "./keytool -list -keystore $EAP_HOME/vault/h1vault.jceks", it works fine. So my question is why I receive an invalid keystore format message, when the keystore is valid and in a recognised format. Is there any way of diagnosing why I might be receiving this message?